# TypeError: dispatch is not a function React button

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, dispatch

Hi im new to react and i just cant understand why this is not working.

this is my product.js file that im trying to change state when i click on the button "addToBasket"

```
import React from "react";
import "./Product.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";

function Product({ id, title, image, price, rating }) {
  const { dispatch } = useStateValue();

  const addToBasket = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TO_BASKET",
      item: {
        id: id,
        title: title,
        image: image,
        price: price,
        rating: rating,
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="product">
      <div className="product__info">
        <p>{title}</p>
        <p className="product__price">
          <small>$</small>
          <strong>{price}</strong>
        </p>
        <div className="product__rating">
          {Array(rating)
            .fill()
            .map((_) => (
              <p>⭐</p>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>

      <img src={image} alt="" />
      <button onClick={addToBasket}>Add to basket</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Product;
```

so i can change one of these states.
i have all the dependencies i need, double checked. Cant understand if its my mistake or some bug

```
export const initialState = {
  basket: [],
  user: null,
};

export const getBasketTotal = (basket) =>
  basket?.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount, 0);

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_USER":
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.user,
      };
    case "ADD_TO_BASKET":
      return {
        ...state,
        basket: [...state.basket, action.item],
      };
    case "REMOVE_FROM_BASKET":
      let newBasket = [...state.basket];
      const index = state.baslet.findIndex(
        (basketItem) => basketItem.id === action.id
      );
      if (index >= 0) {
        newBasket.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
      }
      return { ...state, basket: newBasket };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

edit: This is my StateProvider.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Comment: What is in your `StateProvider`?

Comment: Edited with the stateprovider file

Comment: Have you console logged `dispatch` to see what it actually is?

Comment: The context `value` you've set to the result of `useReducer`. If you check [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) on that hook, you'll see that it returns an array containing the state and the `dispatch` function.

Comment: Console logging just brings me the "TypeError dispatch" error. I just cant understand the docs :c sorry im a beginner

Comment: Its kind of late but this is what worked for me `const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();`